# How do I resize partitions?

Tags: linux, partitioning

I am using a modified version of Crux. After a few days, I realised I made the boot partition too small.

How do I go about growing it? I am using ReiserFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) is your friend.